# Javascript function when called twice does not execute

Tags: javascript, function, async.js

I am trying to understand a tutorial about function sequencing on 'w3schools - Lesson: JS Async', but i am stuck at the below example.

If you have a JS function that is called twice, apparently the order in which the function is called determines which function gets executed, in the example below i would expect the first function to be executed but it's not

The essence of this lesson should be that the declaration of a function does not determine it's execution order, only the way it's called, but i can't grasp it..

Can anyone elaborate or explain the logic of this syntax? Or what is happening under the hood in JS?

Link to tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Function Sequence</h2>

<p>JavaScript functions are executed in the sequence they are called.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myDisplayer(some) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some;
}

function myFirst() {
  myDisplayer("Hello");
}

function mySecond() {
  myDisplayer("Goodbye");
}

myFirst();
mySecond();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not calling any function twice. How is the function not executed? Seems like it works in your example.

Comment: Okay, guys, i added the full code. The function that executes is the Second function "goodbye" Even though the First function is the one called, that is what i mean.

Comment: `mySecond` is called last, so "Goodbye" is the final output. You are just overwriting the previous result "Hello" from the `myFirst` function call. Try changing `innerHTML = some` to `innerHTML += some` and you'll see both results in the correct order.

Comment: Alright, thanks Carabus.. i think i understand what you mean with it being called last and therefore being executed. But the First function is not executing at all even though i called it as well.. i don't understand this. Shouldn't both functions be executed as i am calling them both?

Comment: @JhonattanRapprecht, the first function gets executed, but its result is then immediately overwritten by the second function call. Think about it: You are actually **replacing** (`.innerHTML = ...`) the entire content of the #demo div each time one of the functions is called.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus I see now! So simple.. Thanks my friend! Maybe you should repost this comment as the answer, because it solved the misunderstanding for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify that both functions are called in the correct order by including a `console.log` statement in the `myDisplayer` function.

Because you're overwriting the entire content of `#demo` each time you call the function, you'll only get to see the result of the very last function call.

```js
function myDisplayer(some) {
  console.log(some);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some;
}

function myFirst() {
  myDisplayer("Hello");
}

function mySecond() {
  myDisplayer("Goodbye");
}

myFirst();
mySecond();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Great answer showing great insight into JS. Thanks alot buddy. I forgot that i could check whether the function was executed or not with the console.log function.